# Puppet and windowsfeature - Boolean Error

Tags: puppet, ruby

I'm new to Puppet Enterprise, but trying to learn how to deploy custom class files to Windows servers.  I am attempting to use the opentable/windowsfeature module, but I'm getting an error when my class attempts to run on a node.  It looks like it's throwing this error in the windowsfeature module -

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: "true" is not a boolean.  It looks to be a String at /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/environments/production/modules/windowsfeature/manifests/init.pp:64 on node test-server-02.testdomain.local
>   Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
>   Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

Has anyone seen this error before or know how to resolve it? The module code tries to initialize the variable as false, but I'm confused why when it tries to do a validate_bool($restart), the error is saying it's set to a "true" string value.

Here are a list of my installed modules:
[root@testserver01 ~]# puppet module list
/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/environments/production/modules
├── linux_base_config (???)
├── nanliu-staging (v1.0.2)
├── opentable-windowsfeature (v1.0.0)
├── puppetlabs-concat (v1.1.2)
├── puppetlabs-powershell (v1.0.4)
├── puppetlabs-registry (v1.0.3)
├── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.4.0)
├── puppetlabs-tomcat (v1.2.0)
└── windows_base_config (???)
/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules (no modules installed)
/opt/puppet/share/puppet/modules
├── puppetlabs-pe_accounts (v2.0.2-6-gd2f698c)
├── puppetlabs-pe_concat (v1.1.2-4-g2b7bba2)
├── puppetlabs-pe_console_prune (v0.1.1-4-g293f45b)
├── puppetlabs-pe_inifile (v1.1.4-16-gcb39966)
├── puppetlabs-pe_java_ks (v1.2.4-35-g44fbb26)
├── puppetlabs-pe_postgresql (v3.4.4-15-g32e56ed)
├── puppetlabs-pe_razor (v0.2.1-9-g8d78ec2)
├── puppetlabs-pe_repo (v0.7.7-51-g5ba0427)
├── puppetlabs-pe_staging (v0.3.3-2-g3ed56f8)
├── puppetlabs-puppet_enterprise (v3.7.1-5-ga436912)
└── puppetlabs-reboot (v0.1.8)

Comment: How exactly are you including `windowsfeature` into the catalog?  Where did you try to set the `$restart` value, in hiera or somewhere else?

Comment: +1 just for the nifty tree formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it may look the the problem is coming from the init.pp file in the windowsfeature it almost certainly isn't.  Take a look at the file.  Line 64 is a validation function, that is checking the $restart variable that was almost certainly passed as a parameter using or looked up via hiera.  Short answer is that your issue is somewhere else, most likely where you are sett the '$restart' value to 'true'.

```
52   define windowsfeature (
53        $ensure = 'present',
54        $feature_name = $title,
55        $installmanagementtools = false,
56        $installsubfeatures = false,
57        $restart = false,
58        $source = false
59    ) {
60
61      validate_re($ensure, '^(present|absent)$', 'valid values for ensure are \'present\' or \'absent\'')
62      validate_bool($installmanagementtools)
63      validate_bool($installsubfeatures)
64      validate_bool($restart)
```

> the error is saying it's set to a "true" string value.

A variable with the value of `true` is different from a variable with the value of `"true"`.  One is a string and the other is a boolean.

Comment: That's what I thought, too.  I looked at all of the classes for that variable thinking I inadvertently set it, and it's only referenced in that module.

Comment: What is calling the windowsfeature?  Are you including it yourself, or is some other class including it?  You need to find what is calling it.  The problem is almost certainly there.

Comment: My class - this is it:
        windowsfeature { 'RDS-RD-Server':
                ensure => present,
                restart => 'true',
        }

Comment: It's the quotes isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is the quotes.  Try `{ 'RDS-RD-Server': ensure => present, restart => true, }`.

Comment: Awesome.... it's been one of those Mondays.  Thanks!